# Using LINQ to do complicated queries with datasets

Tags: c#, sql, linq, dataset

I have several datasets that I need to query. Using linq, I end up with code like this..

```
var query =
     from table1 in table_1.AsEnumerable()
     join table2 in table_2.AsEnumerable()
on table1.Field<string>("Value1") equals
   table2.Field<string>("value2") into join1
from joinData in join1.AsEnumerable()
join table1_1 in table_1.AsEnumerable()
on joinData.Field<string>("Value3") equals
   table1_1.Field<string>("Value1")
into join2
from joinData2 in join2.AsEnumerable()
where joinData2.Field<string>("Value4") == "1" ||
      joinData2.Field<string>("Value4") == "2" ||
      joinData2.Field<string>("Value4") == "3" ||
      joinData2.Field<string>("Value4") == "4" ||
      joinData2.Field<string>("Value4") == "5" ||
      joinData2.Field<string>("Value4") == "6" ||
      joinData2.Field<string>("Value4") == "7" ||
      joinData2.Field<string>("Value4") == "8"
select new
{
    Value1 = data1.Field<string>("Value1"),
    Value2 = data1.Field<string>("Value2"),
    Value3 = data1.Field<string>("Value3"),
    Value4 = data1.Field<string>("Value4"),
    Value5 = data1.Field<string>("Value5"),
    Value6 = data1.Field<string>("Value6"),
    Value7 = data1.Field<string>("Value7"),
    Value8 = data1.Field<string>("Value8"),
    Value9 = data1.Field<string>("Value9"),
    Value10 = data1.Field<string>("Value10"),
    Value11 = data1.Field<string>("Value11"),
    Value12 = data1.Field<string>("Value12"),

    etc...
};
```

There has to be an easier way to do this. Is there any way to just query a dataset with an SQL statement?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the WHERE part:

```
where joinData2.Field<string>("Value4") == "1" ||
      joinData2.Field<string>("Value4") == "2" ||
      joinData2.Field<string>("Value4") == "3" ||


where List<string>{ "1", "2", "3", ... }
      .Contains( joinData2.Field<string>("Value4"))
```

And maybe you could refactor the SELECT part into a constructor (of a not-anonymous type).

But no, you cannot apply SQL to datasets (beyond what you're already doing with LINQ).

Consider using an ORM like Entity framework, that would make life a lot easier.